# why every time I want to run a unit test I always get an error and can't even though the code is correct and safe

Tags: android, kotlin

[my problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ucdkR.png)

which I hope to get a solution and be able to solve the problem in my unit test. can it help me because I am also still learning android so a little still not too familiar with android. I don't know anymore because I really need help from all of you stackoverflow users.

Comment: Make sure you examine the build output in the Test Results window, and the HTML file that contains the test results, you'll likely get a better idea of what the issue might be. But based solely on the information you've shared, it's impossible to tell what's wrong.